# API that called from android giving error

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-volley

When I run the API from client, it is giving response(raw) true but when its called it from android, it is giving status 500 error.

> E/Volley: [5518] BasicNetwork.performRequest: Unexpected response code 500 for http://192.168.9.38:8787/WebAPI/daapi/auth
> D/APPLOG: com.android.volley.ServerError

**Android Code:**

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

```
EditText pass,user;
Button login;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    pass  = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtPassword);
    user = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtUser);
    login=(Button)findViewById(R.id.login);

    login.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            register(v);
        }
    });

}

public void register(View view)
{
    RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(MainActivity.this);

    String URL = "http://192.168.9.38:8787/WebAPI/daapi/auth";

    StringRequest postRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST,URL,
            new Response.Listener<String>()
            {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response){
                    Log.d("APPLOG",response);
                    parseJson(response);
                }

            },
            new Response.ErrorListener()
            {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error)
                {
                    Log.d("APPLOG",error.toString());
                }
            }

    ){
        @Override
        protected Map<String,String> getParams()
        {
            Map<String,String> params = new HashMap<String,String>();
            params.put("password",pass.getText().toString().trim());
            params.put("user",user.getText().toString().trim());
            return params;
        }
        @Override
        public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
            HashMap<String, String> headers = new HashMap<String, String>();
            headers.put("Content-Type","application/json;charset=utf-8");
            headers.put("Accept", "application/json, text/plain, */*");
            return headers;
        }

    };
    queue.add(postRequest);
}

public void parseJson(String jsonStr)
{
    JSONObject jsonObj = null;
    try {
        jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);
        Log.d("JSON", "parseJson: "+jsonObj.toString());

    }catch (JSONException e) {

    }
}
```

}

**JAVA API**

@Path("/daapi")
public class Daapi {

```
@POST
@Path("auth")
@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Boolean AuthUser(JsonObject inputJsonObj ) throws Exception {
    Boolean status = false;
    System.out.println("Auth"+inputJsonObj.toString());
    
    String User = inputJsonObj.getString("user");
    String Password = inputJsonObj.getString("password");
    
    System.out.println(" Value "+User+";"+Password);

    if(User=="chistia@mi.com") return true;

}
```

}

When I am testing the API in the rest client, it is showing the response body(raw): true, the request details are below :

{

```
"method": "POST",
"transformRequest": [
    null
],
"transformResponse": [
    null
],
"url": "http://192.168.9.38:8787/WebAPI/daapi/auth",
"headers": {
      "Accept": "application/json, text/plain, */*",
      "Content-Type": "application/json;charset=utf-8"
 },
 "data": "{\n\"user\" : \"chistia@mi.com\",\n\"password\" : \"morshed12\"\n}",
 "timeout": {}
```

}

Comment: 500 means internal server error.

Comment: @Blackbelt, internal server error means? both are in my machine.